CEF4Delphi re-triggering HTML Retrieve after page change
I'm lost and confused with GetHTML methods in CEF4Delphi. No matter how I use them, I get practically the same code that was loaded at the beginning of page load, even if a lot of changes happen on the page. Consider with me the following example.
I load the page https://www.wp.pl/ or https://www.onet.pl/ for which I want to read the headlines of articles every day. After loading the page, the first headlines are of course visible, but I want to read all of them. So I scroll the page and try to read its content again after "loading" new elements that, after a while, are already visible on screen, but after trying to read HTML from the TChromium browser, I still get practically the same code as at the beginning, possibly with some changed line regarding ads on the page.
I use and handle the TChromium component, the display is via the CEFWindowParent component. There are roughly two approaches I've tried that work for reading HTML. First is this proc:
procedure GetHtml;
begin
  Form1.Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.GetSourceProc(
    procedure(const aSource: ustring)
    begin
      html_result := aSource;
    end
  );
end;

and second is:
function GetSourceCEF4: string;
begin
  Form1.Chromium1.RetrieveHTML;
end;

with trigger
procedure TForm1.Chromium1TextResultAvailable(Sender: TObject; const aText: ustring);
begin
  html_result := aText;
end;

and this one is also possible, but of course it is not very suitable for my applications, because this event is not triggered after scrolling.
procedure TForm1.ChromiumBrowserLoadEnd(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser;
  const frame: ICefFrame; httpStatusCode: Integer);
begin
  frame.GetSourceProc(
    procedure(const aSource: ustring)
    begin
      html_result := aSource;
    end
  );
end;

both approaches are quite familiar to CEF users and are described in more detail elsewhere. Of course I wait a few (dozens) seconds before reading HTML.
As I wrote - I have to scroll the page, but when the elements are fully loaded and visible in the screen browser, all the above-mentioned procedures still return the same code as immediately after loading the page from the link. Like no scroll happens. Of course, I mean all possible types of scrolling, both manual (simply with a mouse) and programmatically invoked:

SimulateKeyPress(Form1.Chromium1.Browser, VK_NEXT);
Form1.Chromium1.ExecuteJavaScript('window.scrollBy(0,500)', 'about:blank', 0);

I also tried various found commands in JS but none of them return anything to the TChromium browser:
Form1.Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
  'window.cefQuery({request: document.documentElement.outerHTML});', 'about:blank', 0);

Form1.Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
  'cefQuery = function() {' +
  '  var message = cef.createMessage("htmlContent");' +
  '  message.setArgument(0, document.documentElement.outerHTML);' +
  '  cef.sendMessage(message);' +
  '};' +
  'cefQuery();', 'about:blank', 0);

because none of them ultimately invokes any process trigger, for example OnProcessMessageReceived.
What am I doing wrong, why can't I access the full HMTL code?
PS. Just in case, I know that the code obtained from the context menu of the browser itself (right-click on the window) is a completely different method and copying it to the clipboard has no use for me (which, from what I can see, is hellishly difficult to program).

You do "access the full HTML code" - why would the source resource change after you interacted with the rendered website? You need to access the DOM which is how the engine rendered the website so far. The website's JavaScript is continuing to request more resources off the server - use a browser on that and then see its developer tools how the network has more and more actions as you scroll.

I agree with AmigoJack. Most modern webpages are loading their content dynamically using various scripts while the base HTML of the webpage still stays the same. The only way of tracking the changes is by accessing DOM object that stores current webpage view.

What is you general goal here? If your goal is only getting list of recent articles so that your users might follow their link and open them in their browser I'm guessing news site owners might be willing to provide you with custom script that is capable of retrieving only needed data without loading the full page as this will significantly reduce load of their servers. But of your goal is to copy and repost contents of their articles then you should be aware that in many countries this is already considered to be ilegal since contents of an article is copyrighted by the person who wrote it.

@SilverWarior My goals are simple and scientific. Analysis of headline texts in the context of basic emotions and emotional intensity in the following months/weeks of the year (I will do this in R textminer). Even if news portals in my small country had a philosophy of sharing data via API (sorry, but this is idealistic thinking), most scientific issues still require me not to inform about these scans earlier.

I can understand the need for not informing  them about you gathering data for scientific analysis in order to avoid influencing them and thus changing the gathered data so it would not represent real state. This makes you job a lot harder. I just take a peek into scripts that one of the news site is using in order to perhaps identify which script takes care of dynamically loading of more news headers when scrolling further down the page. ...

... It seems that the web page is randomising the names of many of the used scripts. I'm guessing this is done in order to try and void automated scraping of the website content. So I must admit I have given up in tacking os such script.

@SilverWarior Yes, I am aware of this, which is why searching for objects using standard DOM methods does not seem to solve the problem for me (frequent changes of classes and names). Fortunately, I do not require anything other than article headings, and these are relatively easy to identify by simply parsing regular HTML and, for example, setting some constant values ​​that are related to the heading. Of course, I will have to check from time to time whether the parsing works, but I also have a simple idea for automating this.

TChromiumCore.RetrieveHTML and ICefFrame.GetSourceProc use ICefFrame.GetSource internally.
The MiniBrowser demo shows how to simulate a key press here.
In your case, you should send VK_NEXT simulating WM_KEYDOWN, WM_CHAR and WM_KEYUP like this :
var 
  TempKeyEvent : TCefKeyEvent;
begin
  // WM_KEYDOWN
  TempKeyEvent.kind                    := KEYEVENT_RAWKEYDOWN;
  TempKeyEvent.modifiers               := 0;
  TempKeyEvent.windows_key_code        := VK_NEXT;
  TempKeyEvent.native_key_code         := 0;
  TempKeyEvent.is_system_key           := ord(False);
  TempKeyEvent.character               := #0;
  TempKeyEvent.unmodified_character    := #0;
  TempKeyEvent.focus_on_editable_field := ord(False);
  Chromium1.SendKeyEvent(@TempKeyEvent);
  // WM_CHAR
  TempKeyEvent.kind := KEYEVENT_CHAR;
  Chromium1.SendKeyEvent(@TempKeyEvent);
  // WM_KEYUP
  TempKeyEvent.kind := KEYEVENT_KEYUP;
  Chromium1.SendKeyEvent(@TempKeyEvent);
end;

I've tested TChromiumCore.RetrieveHTML in wp.pl after simulating several VK_NEXT key presses and the HTML is different.
If you prefer to use JavaScript then download CEF4Delphi again and try the DOMVisitor demo. I just updated that demo to get the HTML using JS in the context menu here.
It uses the console trick to send the document.documentElement.outerHTML result.
The result is received in the TChromiumCore.OnConsoleMessage event.
See this answer to know more details about sending information from JavaScript to Delphi.
Edit : One important detail that could cause problems when you try to simulate keyboard events is that the browser must be focused while you send the key events.

I'm using an older version of CEF, 86.0.21. I tested the DOMVisitor demo in it and all three forms of HTML retrieval were consistent with the DOM retrieval result, and of course all gave incomplete page. Does the new DOM procedure really retrieve a larger part of the page than the classic DOM, or the classic HTMLRetrive? And the second question. What I saw in the old DOMVisitor Demo version allowed only to retrieve the result to the clipboard. Does the new procedure bypass the clipboard and allow to directly load the result into a variable?

CEF 86 is extremely old. Try the latest version in GitHub and you'll see that the extracted HTML is much bigger after scrolling several times. You can save the result in a variable as long as you remember that some browser configurations execute the browser events in a thread. In that case you should protect that variable with a critical section. I used the clipboard in the demo just to keep it simple.

Well, our university resources are seriously very limited. We are still working on Windows 7, so the maximum I can do according to the documentation is Chromium 109. And if I understand correctly, CEF 109.1.18. So my question is, is it possible to work on the new CEF project with the older browser version? All I need is a short message that "yes". If it is impossible or extremely difficult, I will simply start looking for an option to upgrade my research equipment.

Yes, it's possible and you only need to modify the TMiniBrowserFrm.Simulatekeyboardpresses1Click procedure in the MiniBrowser demo inside CEF4Delphi 109.1.18 to test it. The HTML is different after scrolling down several times.
